# Undefined parameter when creating nested Kendo grids

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to create a nested grid as explained by the [Kendo grid documentation](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/hierarchy.html)

My main grid populate as expected. Kendo specifies that you have to create a template that will be used to display the nested grids, for example

```
<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.OrderViewModel>()
        .Name("grid_#=EmployeeID#")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Width(70);
            columns.Bound(o => o.ShipCountry).Width(110);
            columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress);
            columns.Bound(o => o.ShipName).Width(200);
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(5)
            .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", 
            "Grid", new { employeeID = "#=EmployeeID#" }))
        )
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .ToClientTemplate()
)
```

The part I'm having trouble with is

```
Name("grid_#=EmployeeID#")
```

and

```
.Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", 
                          "Grid", new { employeeID = "#=EmployeeID#" }))
```

EmployeeID is a parameter that will be passed to the HierarchyBinding_Orders action in the GridController.

When I click on a grid row an exception is thrown

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'EmployeeID' is undefined

How exactly do I populate the EmployeeID parameter? I tried "EmployeeID" and "Model.EmployeeID". Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok EmployeeID was not part of my Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.OrderViewModel which is specified as the model to be used by the grid. I added EmployeeID to this model and everything worked as expected.